# How to calculate/record attachments' file names using Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, vbscript, attachments

I have a point feature class containing attachments corresponding to jpg files (sometime more than one jpg per feature).
I would like to use the "field calculator" to calculate/record a new field that would contain file paths or names of attachment files.
Does someone know how to do that?
I am new to Python and VB script...

Comment: Could you please supply a little more context--maybe a screenshot of the attribute table?  I am having a hard time visualizing your dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that you are trying to update the name of the file in the attribute table with the point layers unique ID of some type e.g. changing Temp646.jpg to CB1.jpg.

This can be done by joining the related attachment table to the feature class and then using field calculator to update the ATT_NAME column in your attachments table.

The steps are:

1. Add Feature class and attachment table to mxd
2. Conduct a join using between the attachment table and feature class using GlobalID and REL_GLOBALID and enable editing
3. Open the attachment table with the join in place and you then can use the field calculator to update the ATT_NAME field.
4. "CB " + !your table column value! +".jpg"  The expression uses python syntax so make sure you flip the radio button on top of the field calc