# Extract attachments with increment for duplicate values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I am using Arcgis Desktop 10.4.1 and Arcgis Collector.

I have joined the globalid and rel_globalid as explained [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96127/how-to-calculate-record-attachments-file-names-using-field-calculator/96162#96162)

I almost what I want, except for the counter for the duplicated .jpg files. I want them to have a suffix like _1,_2,_3. This is my result:

[image]

How can I add a counter that does the naming in the way I want, and still extracts the attachments?

Comment: Can you please post your working code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change the string in the table like this:

[image]

Then this should work:

```
import arcpy
from collections import Counter
fc='C:\geodatabase.gdb\feature_class' #Change to match your data

#Add all att_names to a list
attnames=[i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,'ATT_NAME')]

#Create a new list and add count
newattnames=[]
item_count=Counter()
for item in attnames:
    item_count[item]+=1
    newattnames.append('{}_{}{}'.format(item.split('.')[0],item_count[item],'.jpg'))

def newvalue():
    for value in newattnames:
        yield value
g=newvalue()

#Update field 'NEW_ATT_NAME'. Add this field to the table prior to running the code
#If you want to overwrite current values change 'NEW_ATT_NAME' to 'ATT_NAME' below
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,'NEW_ATT_NAME') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=g.next()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```